# Client Server programming in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, client, sockets

Here is source code for multithreaed server and client in python.

In the code client and server closes connection after the job is finished.
I want to keep the connections alive and send more data over the same connections to **avoid overhead of closing and opening sockets every time**.

Following code is from : http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Basic-Threading-in-Python/1/

```
import pickle
import socket
import threading

# We'll pickle a list of numbers:
someList = [ 1, 2, 7, 9, 0 ]
pickledList = pickle.dumps ( someList )

# Our thread class:
class ClientThread ( threading.Thread ):

   # Override Thread's __init__ method to accept the parameters needed:
   def __init__ ( self, channel, details ):

      self.channel = channel
      self.details = details
      threading.Thread.__init__ ( self )

   def run ( self ):

      print 'Received connection:', self.details [ 0 ]
      self.channel.send ( pickledList )
      for x in xrange ( 10 ):
         print self.channel.recv ( 1024 )
      self.channel.close()
      print 'Closed connection:', self.details [ 0 ]

# Set up the server:
server = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
server.bind ( ( '', 2727 ) )
server.listen ( 5 )

# Have the server serve "forever":
while True:
   channel, details = server.accept()
   ClientThread ( channel, details ).start()
```

---

```
import pickle
import socket
import threading

# Here's our thread:
class ConnectionThread ( threading.Thread ):

   def run ( self ):

      # Connect to the server:
      client = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
      client.connect ( ( 'localhost', 2727 ) )

      # Retrieve and unpickle the list object:
      print pickle.loads ( client.recv ( 1024 ) )

      # Send some messages:
      for x in xrange ( 10 ):
         client.send ( 'Hey. ' + str ( x ) + '\n' )

      # Close the connection
      client.close()

# Let's spawn a few threads:
for x in xrange ( 5 ):
   ConnectionThread().start()
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Spawning a new thread for every connection is a **really bad** design choice.
What happens if you get hit by a lot of connections?

In fact, using threads to wait for network IO is not worth it. Your program gets really complex and you get absolutely **no benefit** since waiting for network in threads won't make you **wait faster**. You only lose by using threads in this case.

The following text is from python documentation:

> There are only two ways to have a
>   program on a single processor do “more
>   than one thing at a time.”
>   Multi-threaded programming is the
>   simplest and most popular way to do
>   it, but there is another very
>   different technique, that lets you
>   have nearly all the advantages of
>   multi-threading, without actually
>   using multiple threads. It’s really
>   only practical if your program is
>   largely I/O bound. If your program is
>   processor bound, then pre-emptive
>   scheduled threads are probably what
>   you really need. Network servers are
>   rarely processor bound, however.

And if it is a processor bound server case. you could always leave another process/thread to do the processor part. Continuing:

> If your operating system supports the
>   select system call in its I/O library
>   (and nearly all do), then you can use
>   it to juggle multiple communication
>   channels at once; doing other work
>   while your I/O is taking place in the
>   “background.” Although this strategy
>   can seem strange and complex,
>   especially at first, it is in many
>   ways easier to understand and control
>   than multi-threaded programming.

So instead of using threads, use non-blocking input/output: collect the sockets in a list and use an event loop with [select.select](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html#select.select) to know which socket has data to read. Do that in a single thread.

You could choose a python asynchronous networking framework like [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) to do that for you. That will save you a lot of headaches. Twisted's code has been improved for years, and covers some corner cases you'll take time to master.

**EDIT**: Any existing async IO libraries (like Twisted) are python code. You could have written it yourself, but it has already been written for you. I don't see why you wouldn't use one of those libraries and write your own **worst** code instead, since you are a beginner. Networing IO is hard to get right.

Comment: How to do asynchronous networking without using twisted or any other library ?
Please suggest.

Comment: @david: I just did so in the 3rd paragraph of my question.

Comment: @david: You can't do anything without using libraries. Everything is a library. From a certain point of view, python itself is a library. You can always copy parts or the entire twisted code inside your application and pretend you wrote it. Twisted is pure python.

Comment: @david: in other words, twisted is the code you could have written yourself. Only it has already been written for you. I don't see why you wouldn't use it (or any other library for async IO) and write your own *worst* code instead.

Comment: @nosklo: Thanks for suggestion but isnt there any very simple example to understand how actually asynch n/w works in python.

Comment: What's about Tornado?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but don't call `close()` if you don't want to close the connection...

Answer (score 0):

For an example of a client the keeps a TCP connection open and uses a familiar protocol,
look at the [source](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/telnetlib.py?rev=63788&view=log) of the [telnetlib module](http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html#module-telnetlib). (sorry, someone else will have to answer your threading questions.)

An example of a server that keeps a TCP connection open is in the source for the [SocketServer module](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html) (any standard Python installation includes the source).